# How to create foreign key constraint in microsoft sql server 2012?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to create foreign key constraint in microsoft sql server 2012 with following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE Period
(
    Period_ID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Training_History_Start_Period datetime NULL,
    Training_History_End_Period datetime NULL,
    Training_Target_Start_Period datetime NULL,
    Training_Target_End_Period datetime NULL,
    Scoring_History_Start_Period datetime NULL,
    Scoring_History_End_Period datetime NULL,
    Scoring_Target_Start_Period datetime NULL,
    Scoring_Target_End_Period datetime NULL
);

CREATE TABLE RiskScore
(
    Period_ID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Period(Period_ID),
    Driver_ID int NULL,
    Risk_Score numeric(10,5) NULL,
    Run_on datetime NULL
);
```

At the time of inserting data into DB, Period table taking desired data but RiskScore table is taking in Period_ID column. This column is not taking Period_ID from Period table.

Someone help me please.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you expecting `RiskScore` to automatically get data from `Period`? It is just a `Foreign Key` and you will need to supply the values

Answer (score 0):

Foreign Key: Definition

A foreign key is a way to enforce referential integrity within your SQL Server database. A foreign key means that values in one table must also appear in another table. The referenced table is called the parent table while the table with the foreign key is called the child table.

In your case,

Period is your parent table, RiskScore is your child table.

Foreign key enforce referential integrity but it does not bring the data from parent to child table. You should manually populate the values to your child table. Suppose if the given value in the child table not exists in parent then you will get an error message.